# When does firefox call nss_init?

Tags: firefox, nss

I have my very own privacy CA library. So now I want to integrate it with the mozilla nss. 
So every time when my firefox want to access https page, it will call this library via nss.
my problem is, i could not find, at with point (or with source file) within firefox that make a call for nss_init stuff..

help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are actually looking for [NSS_Initialize, which is loaded here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/src/nsNSSComponent.cpp#1626).  This function will be called the first time an https url is loaded.